# check if value inside the range

Tags: python, range

A configuration variable `range` maybe configed as follows:

```
range="5"
```

or:

```
range="1-5"
```

Now for a given parameter:

```
level=3
```

How to check if `level` is inside the `range` or not quickly?

---

I know I can split the `range` and then compare them one by one, I just wonder if there is any pythonic manner which would be more efficient.

---

Current method:

```
def check_range(rng,level):
    if not rng:
        return true;
    levels=rng.split('-')
    if len(levels) > 1:
        return level >= int(levels[0]) and level <=int(levels[1])
    else:
        return level==int(levels[0])


print check_range("0-10",4)
print check_range("5-10",4)
print check_range("5",4)
print check_range("4",4)
```

BTW, this method will be called once per request.

Comment: Why not use 2 variables, start = x, end = y ?

Comment: I'd say convert the string `range` to a `range()` first, and then `if level in range:`

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I think so. But I google and get nothing by 'python range from string'

Comment: @at0ma: As I said the ```range``` is set by user through the configuration file which I have no access.

Comment: Try writing some code to do it. If you run into problems, ask a specific question.

Comment: Also rename your range variable because that's a python keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a foolproof way of doing it although it is not the most efficient:

```
from re import findall as f

r="5"

level=3

a = f(r'(\d+)?-?(\d+)', r)[0]

try:
    print int(a[0]) <= level <= int(a[1])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    print 0 <= level <= int(a[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want. Shorter than mine.

Comment: @hguser, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Sorry, I miss that. :)

Answer (score 2):

If is python like you said, that range value need to be split:

Function definition:

```
 def check(range, level):
      points = range.split('-');
      if len( points ) == 1 :
        //only 1 item in your range
        if  level == int( points[0] ) :
          return true;
      if len( points ) == 2 : 
        if level >= int( points[0]) && level <=int(points[1]):
          return true;
      return false;
```

Call your function:

```
level = 3;
range="5-1"
check( range, level );
```